AWS Amplify Cognito: Handle user session across all tabs without storing user data in local storage
I have a Vue application that uses AWS Amplify for authentication. The current setup saves the Cognito user-specific data, such as tokens and user info, in localStorage because of the default amplify configuration. Since storing critical user data in localStorage exposes it to CSRF and XSS, I'm looking for other ways to handle user session. One of the ways to do is to change the storage to sessionStorage as shown below:
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // config
    oauth: {
      // config
    }
  },
  storage: window.sessionStorage
})

this solves the security issues by saving the user data in sessionStorage, but since the user data is session-specific (available only in the current tab) if I open the app URL in a new tab within the same browser, the user becomes turned to signed out because of the unavailability of tokens, etc.
Is there a way to maintain user session without saving user data in localStorage or even to sessionStorage?
